# forcing a scrollbar for fixed element accomodation

Tags: jquery, css, simplemodal

i am using the jquery simplemodal plugin,

now i've set it up so that it uses a dynamic height, based on the content within it.

however i've run into a bit of a snag here, it seems that if i make the browser window smaller, it does not accomodate for the height of the simplemodal element, therefore some things within the container are hidden off-screen.

i've tried adding:

```
body {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

and this accomplishes nothing. in fact, the body will scroll when resized based on the content of the page, not the simplemodal element height.

is there a way for me to force scrollbars if a fixed element is overflowing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
overflow: scroll
```

This forces scrollbars to appear, even when not needed.

Comment: this does not resolve the issue. the problem is the page is not scrolling to accomodate the ABSOLUTE-positioned element.

Comment: It should. Are you sure it's not a `fixed` position element? If it's `fixed`, then yeah it won't work and there's not much you can do about it.

Comment: looks like it is fixed. my bad. so theres nothing i can do about it?

Comment: Not that I know of, other than changing it to absolute and adding an `onscroll` event to keep it in place.

Answer (score 0):

overflow:scroll;
if you only want it to show for an instance(s), put that in a class you can chain to your simplemodal element.